# Merging average of time series corresponding to time span in a different data set

Tags: merge, time-series, stata

I have two datasets, one with contracts and one with market prices. The gist of what I am trying to accomplish is to find the average value of a time series that corresponds to a period of time in a cross-sectional data set. Please see below.

Example Dataset 1:

```
Beginning Ending    Price
1/1/2014  5/15/2014 $19.50
3/2/2012  10/9/2015 $20.31
...
1/1/2012 1/8/2012 $19.00
```

In the example above there are several contracts, the first spanning from January 2014 to May 2014, the second from March 2012 to October 2015. Each one has a single price. The second dataset has weekly market prices.

Example Dataset 2:

```
Date     Price
1/1/2012 $18
1/8/2012 $17.50
....
1/15/2015 $21.00
```

I would like to find the average "market price" (i.e. the average of the price in dataset 2) between the beginning and ending period for each contract on dataset 1. So, for the third contract from 1/1/2012 to 1/8/2012, from the second dataset the output would be (18+17.50)/2 = 17.75. Then merge this value back to the original dataset.

I work with Stata, but can also work with R or Excel.

Also, if you have a better suggestion for a title I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Is the second dataset a panel or a single time series?

Comment: The second dataset is a single time series, contains date and market price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cross the contracts cross section data with the time series, which forms every pairwise combination, drop the prices from outside the date range, and calculate the mean like this:

```
/* Fake Data */
tempfile ts ccs

clear
input str9 d p_daily
"1/1/2012" 18
"1/8/2012" 17.50
"1/15/2015" 21.00 
end
gen date = date(d,"MDY")
format date %td
drop d
rename date d
save `ts'
clear
input id str8 bd str9 ed p_contract
1 "1/1/2014"  "5/15/2014" 19.50
2 "3/2/2012"  "10/9/2015" 20.31
3 "1/1/2012"  "1/8/2012" 19.00
end
foreach var of varlist bd ed {
    gen date = date(`var',"MDY")
    format date %td
    drop `var'
    rename date `var'
}
save `ccs'

/* Calculate Mean Prices and Merge Contracts Back In */
cross using `ts'
sort id d
keep if d >= bd & d <=ed
collapse (mean) mean_p = p_daily, by(id bd ed p_contract)
merge 1:1 id using `ccs', nogen
sort id
```

This gets you something like this:

```
  id   p_contract          bd          ed   mean_p  
     1       19.5   01jan2014   15may2014        .  
     2      20.31   02mar2012   09oct2015       21  
     3         19   01jan2012   08jan2012    17.75
```